# Using a formula's output as a cell reference number for a different formula in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So I am trying to have a cell pull the first non-blank value from another sheet's list (we will call this other sheet AG Test). I believe the formula I have will work but I want to have it use the array values (currently set to AY15:CC15) by pulling the text from formula outputs on the non-reference sheet (Sheet2) as shown in cells D4 and E15. How would I put the values that are calculated in these cells as the array values in the larger index formula so they pull values from those cells in the other sheet (AG Test)? Is this possible?

Basically making the value showing in the green cell be used in the green lettering in the formula and the orange cell's value in the orange lettering in the formula.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You need to use INDIRECT function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INDIRECT()` function:

`... INDIRECT("'AG TEST'!" & D4 & ":" & E4) ...`

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you.

Comment: @AGARRETT if you find this solution acceptable, then please consider Accepting as the answer. Click on the check mark. This lets others know it's been solved.